# How to connect to flexlm licence manager?

Tags: flexlm

I have a flexlm licence manager running on a remote server.

Does anyone know how to poll the server to find out what licences are in use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the only way to get licence usage over a network is to poll the flexlm daemon using:

```
lmutil lmstat -a -c <port-number@license-server>
```

I've not marked orenhg's repsonse as an answer as it is advertising his product rather than answering the question.

Comment: for future readers, the < and > characters should not be included in the command.

Comment: Or, to test the LM_LICENSE_FILE var assignment (and possible save typing) use:
`lmutil lmstat -a -c %LM_LICENSE_FILE%`